# Get all values present on a table for a given attribute without duplicates on a DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have this table:

```
Role        Alias       GrantedBy ...
Admin       xyz         xxx
Admin       abc         fff
Trainer     efg         kfk
Manager     lmn         jfj
Trainer     ijk         iui
Misc.       opq         jdj
```

Is there a way to get API Gateway to return something like `['Admin', 'Trainer','Manager', 'Misc.']` using a `Mapping Template`? If this is not possible, I can think of multiple ways of manipulating the results of a query to get the result I want but, what would be the best approach?

For example, would you recommend using a GSI that could help me accomplish this task?

### Approach #1

Get all results in the DB and then reducing the `Role` attribute values into to an array of unique values,

*I would consider this to be very bad in terms of performance and efficiency.*

### Approach #2

Create a GSI or configure the table so I can query in a way that returns all values available in the `Role` attribute.

So I would get something like:

```
Role
Admin
Admin
Trainer
Manager
Trainer
Misc.
```

And then I could iterate through that array and get the unique values.

*Significantly better as I would be fetching just role values and then I would de-dupe them.*

### Approach #3

Configure the table so I can do something like a `SELECT DISTINCT ROLES FROM TABLE_XYZ`

Maybe declaring the `projection expression` declaration and just specify `Role`?

This would be ideal but I'm not sure if this is even possible in DynamoDB.

*Optimal solution?*

I'm wondering if maybe I'm trying to get DynamoDB to do something that it is not designed to do...

I come from SQL and am learning NoSQL and its pretty difficult to change how my brain is wired.

I appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is my view on this problem. In the meantime, any suggestions and feedbacks are welcomed :)

**Approach #1**: Under no circumstances should you use it unless this is just a one-off case.

**Approach #2**: IMO, this is the go-to solution with the minimum change and extra effort required.

**Approach #3**: Not sure what you mean. Could you clarify how you are gonna do it?

=====================

**Bonus Approach #4 for you:** Maintain a list of unique roles.

This is very common in NoSQL. Some people call it pre-aggregation. You can think of it as something similar to a running SUM/AVG/COUNT etc.

Every time you need to add a new record, check its value of the role attribute against the list of unique roles that you maintain first. If the role doesn't exist yet, add it to the list and then proceed with the normal procedure.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping out. Regarding approach #3, if I were using SQL, I should be able to query the table with something like `SELECT DISTINCT [column name] FROM [table name]` and I would get a list of all unique values for that column (SQL would get rid of duplicates), which is basically what I need. I was wondering if there was a way I could configure the table so I could do something similar (maybe by adding an extra helper column, a GSI, ...).

Comment: Now, about approach #2, does it make sense to specify that I only what DynamoDB to return **just** the values for the `role` attribute with `projectionExpression`? Will I need a GSI?

Comment: No, generally speaking, this type of DISTINCT aggregation is not supported in NoSQL.

Comment: yes, you can project just the column you want along with the mandatory key columns.

Comment: I think I like approach #3, and will do some research to get it done, but I'm interested in your suggested approach #4. Would that be a separate table that contains all available roles? I see a really strong relationship between the new table and the role attribute. Is there something like a 'foreign key'in DynamoDB? I think I should stop thinking about SQL stuff since Im doing NoSQL lol

Comment: haha, SQL to NoSQL mindset transition can be hard, isn't it :) Regarding your question about my approach #4, if you can fit that into your primary table by using, for example,  general PK and SK, then go for it. If not, it _can_ be done in a separate table, but in that case, I would personally prefer approach #2.

Comment: how many distinct roles will you have? and how often would you expect they change? it feels like a whole table to manage roles might be overkill unless the cardinality of your roles is something on the order of hundreds or more..  it most cases, for roles, I'd expect cardinality to be in the range of low tens max which can be stored in a single text field. even for larger cardinalities, you can store as a bitmask etc.